# How to extract the specific contents from the html doc I grasp

Tags: python, html, url, beautifulsoup

I'm new on Beautifulsoup and urllib.
What I want to do is to read the data from [pm25.in](http://www.pm25.in/api_doc),which is a website offering atmospheric quality data of China.

#### My early attempt

```
### set a specific city name, token is the public key for free use
city = 'zhuhai'
html_doc = urllib.urlopen("http://www.pm25.in/api/querys/co.json?        
city=zhuhai&token=5j1znBVAsnSf5xQyNQyq").read().decode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
```

#### Result

```html
<html>

<body>
  <p>
    [{"aqi":29,"area":"珠海","co":0.591,"co_24h":0.955,"position_name":"吉大","primary_pollutant":null,"quality":"优","station_code":"1367A","time_point":"2016-01-07T20:00:00Z"},{"aqi":51,"area":"珠海","co":0.913,"co_24h":1.059,"position_name":"前山","primary_pollutant":"颗粒物(PM10)","quality":"良","station_code":"1368A","time_point":"2016-01-07T20:00:00Z"},{"aqi":35,"area":"珠海","co":0.699,"co_24h":0.885,"position_name":"唐家","primary_pollutant":null,"quality":"优","station_code":"1369A","time_point":"2016-01-07T20:00:00Z"},{"aqi":52,"area":"珠海","co":0.874,"co_24h":0.949,"position_name":"斗门","primary_pollutant":"颗粒物(PM10)","quality":"良","station_code":"1370A","time_point":"2016-01-07T20:00:00Z"},{"aqi":67,"area":"珠海","co":0.769,"co_24h":0.962,"position_name":null,"primary_pollutant":"臭氧8小时","quality":"良","station_code":null,"time_point":"2016-01-07T20:00:00Z"}]
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

#### My target

here is the dataframe which I edit manually as a template.

http://i4.tietuku.com/71f10394dbedd8d3.png

I want to know how to extract these useful data from the raw html_doc
I have tried `soup.find_all()`, but I don't know how to set the paraments to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json` module to convert your `soup` into a list:

```
import json
...
l = soup.p.get_text()  # find p tag and extract text from it
result = json.loads(l) # convert text into python list
```

Now that you have the list `result` you can manipulate the data the way you need.

Comment: @HanZhengzu Great! Please, consider accepting/upvoting my answer then. That'll help others who are searching for the same kind of problem